# Guest user cart in codigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, reference, e-commerce

I want to add a product in the cart for the guest user

I have created on session by inserting the guest user information in database as follows in my header file which is been including on every view as common

```
<?php $this->load->view('common/header'); ?>
```

Below it is what I used at the top of my header file

```
<?php   if($this->session->userdata('user_id')=='') 
{           
$this->home_model->addguestUser();  

}
$info = $this->home_model->productinfo($ProductID);
?>
```

Now this calls the information is used by my home model to create a session according to user_id from database

The first thing I want is to stop to interact with the database because whenever anybody visits my site the data is add as guest in the database which is very dangerous if the number of people visits on my site increased

I want to create session without making any major changes in my current code and I want to create a session with some random variables and then use it to every page

**My current flow of data is as follows**

1. Whenever any persons visits my site then the guest user is created automatically.
2. Then this session is used throughout the site in the static page also
3. If the user goes and adds product in the user cart it will automatically gets added in the cart as well as in the entry goes in database
4. If he is the guest user and adds the product in the cart then after he clicks on the checkout page he will first ask to login to his id if he is registered user .

**What I want the flow should be**

1. As of now the database interaction for the guest user should not be there i.e if he is guest user then the database use should be not there.
2. But the session should be created for the guest user also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For guest user don't add selected product into database but just store in session. Save data in session for guest user. Once they click for checkout ask them for login or register. After login add their saved(saved in session) data in database.

If they don't register or login, session would automatically destroyed when they leave your site.

Hope this is what you want.

Comment: Can you show me how to add product in cart using session

Comment: Just store the cart data in session variable whatever you are inserting in database.